# Parse data from ajax request to json

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm trying to send data from Ajax to a php page, I can send the data without trouble, however I have issues to access the data from the PHP page.

My ajax code :

```
 $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'gen/gen_dup.php',
    data: data,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log('Duplicata MB OK', response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('error', response);
});
};
```

That is my php code :

```
$data = json_decode(var_dump($_POST), true);
```

And I'm getting that back from the PHP page :

```
array(1) { ["{"title":"Monsieur","name":"aaa","address":"zzz","reference":"zzzzzzee","collector":"1"}"]=> string(0) "" }
```

When I'm trying to access it with :

```
echo $data[0]['reference']; // It doesn't work with $data['reference'] either
```

I get no result. I'm obtaining the same array if I use :

```
$data = var_dump($_POST);
```

Which leads me to believe that the Json decoding is not actually doing anything there. Any suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: If I use       $data = json_decode($_POST, true);  it doesn't return anything at all

Comment: Post the result of `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Array ( [{"title":"Monsieur","name":"aaa","address":"zzz","reference":"zzzzzzee","collector":"1"}] => )

Comment: it is impossible for your `json_encode(var_dump())` to return anything. var_dump has a `void` return type - it only does output, it can NEVER return anything.

Comment: `json_decode` __DECODES__ data. You need to encode it - `json_encode`.

Comment: What is the value of `data` passed to a script?

Comment: Don't encode your data. You already get an array that you can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You have to serialize your data accordingly for this to work. [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) or AngularJS [$httpParamSerializer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer) can do this for you.

Your post doesnt say it explicitely, but `$http()` looks like AngularJS. In this case:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'gen/gen_dup.php',
    data: data,
    transformRequest: $httpParamSerializer //or jQuery.param,
                                           //or $httpParamSerializerJQLike
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
    }
}).then(....
```

Or you use `Content-Type: application/json` and not worry about serialization.